# Solution for Chrome app not supporting after December 2022

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, migration, google-chrome-app, tcpserver

I do have a Chrome app with following functionality.

- The app communicate with another program which is running in the company network in a bi-directional manner. (It is a bi-directional communication with a medical analyzer). I have used chrome.sockets.tcpServer facility.
- The app gets data from the analyzer and communicate with a cloud hosted application and sends results to the analyzer program.
- This is a personal using app inside the company only and not expecting to add to the Chrome app store.
- Now when I start the application, I get a message that saying that the app will not open after December 2022. I think it's because the Chrome app stops from developing.
- I tried the app migration guidelines from Google, but I didn't get any good catch.
- Chrome extensions will not work as they do not have the mentioned access facility.

So what will be the best option for me? I'm not a big fan of desktop applications. So is there any option more closer to Chrome web app in JavaScript? I use Codeigniter for my cloud application. I'm expecting to do this with minimum or no modification for the production cloud. Thanks in advance.

-- Edit --

This is how my app connects to the application in the company network.

```
var serverSocketId;

chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(createInfo) {
  
    serverSocketId = createInfo.socketId;
 
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(serverSocketId, '10.0.0.5', 3000, function(resultCode) {
        if (resultCode < 0) {
            console.log("Error listening:" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Then it communicates with cloud application with JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX Does PWA supports it? I meant for tcp server functionality?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your kindness. I'm bit confused here. Can I achieve the same result as chrome.sockets.tcpServer with websockets? https://blog.asial.co.jp/1267 this is the source I used to build the app

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry. I added the connecting code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248503/discussion-between-tdj-and-jaromanda-x).